# How to generate new filename for the output file (.xml file) while executing a PHP program each time

Tags: php, xml, file, filenames, sitemap

I am running a PHP program ,It generate output a site map map which is in .XML format. For me each time when I run PHP program the site map (which is in .xml format) should have new (non repeated ) file name says first time hello1.xml
second time when i run same php program it should get hello2.xml, third time hello3.xml................

```
My .php program generate the output in same server in .xml format.The name of the output file should be changed automatically each time when run Php program.
```

Kindly help.

Comment: you need to create recursive function to check file exist in your path and rename if already exist

Comment: As an alternate you can add date time stamp to file name. Eg. hello_20160906123051. Which will always be unique and also easy to order.

Comment: yes @Sasikumarhx that is also fine but if he want auto index 1,2,3 he need to create function for that

Comment: Thank you Minesh patel and Sasikumarhx  i go with 
<?php
$date = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($date);
?>
solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
function getNewFileName($destFile)
{           
        $fileInfo = pathinfo($destFile);         
        if (file_exists($destFile)) {
            $index = 1;
            $baseName = $fileInfo['filename'] . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
            while((file_exists($fileInfo['dirname'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $baseName)) ) {
                $baseName = $fileInfo['filename']. '_' . $index . '.' . $fileInfo['extension'];
                $index ++;
            }            
            $destFileName = $baseName;                                  
        } else {
            return $fileInfo['basename'];
        }

        return $destFileName;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i gone with the solution 
<?php
$date = date_create();
echo date_timestamp_get($date);
?>

Comment: ok great. the above solution create file name like actual file name_1 ,actual file name_2 based on file available in that directory.